# Bad Character in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

i ran into a simple problem, which I think you guys can solve. I am programming javascript, where I use the following code to replace all strings in a string with another string:

```
str = str.replace(/find/g,”replace”)
```

Yes, the code works, but what I want to do is:

```
str = str.replace(/</p>/g,”replace”)
```

It won't work because of:

```
</p>.
```

It dosen't like the /.

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an escape:

```
str.replace(/<\/p>/g, "replace");
              ^--- escape char.
```

Comment: Thanks for ultra-quick respond! Nice answer and thank you :) I will accept the answer when I can ...

Answer (score 2):

Escape `/` with another `\.` Like `<\/p>`

Should work.